# Android Studio can't login to GitHub

Tags: android-studio, authentication, github

I'm getting this issue while logging in on GitHub on Android Studio:

> Can't login: Can't get user info 404: Not found

[image]

Has someone faced this issue? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use "github.com" as host (not the whole clone url), and my github login and password and can login without any issues.

Answer (score 113):

I have faced this problem too. Try using token to login.

Log in to github.com on the browser. Go to Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens. There you can create a new token and then, go back to Android Studio, select Enter Token at the login prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only answer that helped me.

Comment: Same for me, I have no idea what is this happening?

Comment: It seems Github won't accept user/pass logins anymore (effective from Aug. 13, 2021): https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations. So, better to start using tokens anyway.

Comment: why is this? i can copy and paste my username and password ive checked everything and i cant log in, i can do it with a token but i dont want to! i want to sign in like always lol

Comment: be sure to enable "repo", "admin:org", "gist" in order for the token to work

Comment: This is the correct answer now due to login/pass aren't working anymore. Thanks dude!!!

Comment: Thanx. its help me too

Comment: This worked for me -- thanks.  When you create the token, you need to give it at least the following scopes: repo, gist, read:org.

Answer (score 17):

I'm working on 4.1.1 Android Studio and it didn't allow me to log in with Login + Password neither.

So I succeeded generating a token from Github (Account -> Settings -> Personal access tokens - > Generate new token), but make sure before generating the token to check the "repo", "gist" and "read:org" options.

Everything's working fine from there.

Have fun coding !

Comment: Now in : "Account -> Settings ->Developer settings ->Personal access tokens - > Generate new token.

Answer (score 12):

So, I know it's been 6 years now, but since I didn't find the solution that worked for me, I decided to share here.

**Only step: Go to Settings > Version Control > Git > Mark "Use credential Helper" box and you're done.**

Hope this helps someone, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, only your answer helped!

Comment: This worked, but it seems a bit magical to me and I can't find any documentation on this option (what it does and how it works, etc.).

Comment: I was getting an error when I generated and entered a personal access token before (Invalid Authentication, blah blah) and this fixed it!!

Answer (score 10):

In host you only have to put 'http://github.com'

Nothing more

Answer (score 9):

you can use `Token` for login in  android studio .

[image]

1.go to your `github profile`

2.click on `settings`

3.go to `Developer settings`

4.click on `Personal access tokens`

5.`Generate new token`

and copy it  and paste it in above window on android studio.

Comment: This helped me. I think the root cause is that I am using two-step verification and android studio cannot use SMS and my phone to verify the access.

Comment: May I know what is the reason use token option is not available on login prompt.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was that the repository URL was set with `http://` but the credential goes to the same URL but with `https://`.
changing the repository URL to `https://` solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

1- Go to your github page,

2- Open Settings menu and create a new token

3- Copy new token

4- Open Androdi studio goto VCS -> import into version control -> Share Project in Git Hub login

5- Use Token option

6- Paste token you created and copied

7- Click login

No need to change url

I am using Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 4):

### If you can't find the access token option in Android Studio

I was simply not able to find the option to add the access token to Android Studio, as the credential was not working.

If you click on the **`Add Account`** option as shown below, you won't find the option to enter the access token (bad UI I'll say):

[Add Account with no option for access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPROq.jpg)

#### Solution:

Click the small **`+`** icon at the bottom of the dialog box to find a menu > choose **`Log In with Token`** to find the option.

Generate a token from Github and enter it here. It will be done!
[Where to find the access token option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvdif.jpg)

Comment: it'd be better off creating a button to action to generate a new token and update the current account. Instead of trying to figure out where the Github settings are located. Your answer solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the  this issue for my private repository, So in Github I created new access token and given all access for this token. Use this token in Android studio, It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm done with this problem, use the token to login.
create tokens in this way;
simply checklist on

-repo
-admin:org
-gist
[Ceklist Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdGPu.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use token to solve this problem.

Login to GitHub account in browser
Go to  SETTINGS-> DEVELOPER SETTINGS->PERSONAL ACCESS TOKENS
here you can create token with suitable scopes.
Remember that selecting scopes is important to access token in android studio.
After that just copy the generated token and paste in android studio.

Have a fun with coding!

Comment: Can I select all the scopes?

Answer (score 2):

I have face this same issue with both Mac and Windows. Creating a personal access token always solved this issue for me. Sign into github click on on account > setting> Developers Settings > Personal Access Tokens

Comment: Hey KevinSom98 This answer really already exists https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957496/6138467 - it would be better to upvote that one I think.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'https://github.com/' and my credentials, I get access

Answer (score 1):

From Android Studio.

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Github
3. Make sure you login in using a created Auth Token Key from Github

From Github.

1. Go to Preferences
2. Go to Developer Mode
3. Generate a New Token Key and give it all the rights to access Github account
4. Copy new Generated key into Android Access token and enter OK when done.

Answer (score 0):

**From Android Studio.**

Go to Settings
Go to Github
Make sure you login in using a created Auth Token Key from Github

**From Github website**

Go to Settings
Go to Developer Settings
Generate a New Token Key
Give a alias to the Token key
Mark **repo, admin:org, gist**.
Click on Generate token button
Copy new Generated key into Android Access token and enter OK when done.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps ---

1. Go to file >> setting >> version control >> add account
2. then login.
3. If can't login message is displaying then you have to generate the token. 
   Go to Settings >> Developer settings >> Personal access tokens.(make sure to check fields like select all repo, select `read:org`(inside- `admin:org`), select gist).
4. When you paste git url use `.git` at the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SSH (forget https) (E.g., don't use https url for cloning)
2. Use Personal Access Token (PAT) (forget username/password)

> (e.g., Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token)

3. Update git to latest version (e.g., 2.35.1)  //I think this is important
4. In Github, Uncheck Settings > Developer Settings > Keep my email addresses private

Conclusion: You add Personal Access token in Github. Then from any IDE (e.g., Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA etc.) you can add remote using ssh (e.g.,  name: origin, URL: git@github.com:your_github_username/your_git_repo.git. That's it

If not already done,

5. Configure git global username and email

   > git config --global user.name "your_username" && git config --global user.email "your_email"

**If in windows, you can add windows credentials for your user**, control panel > users > manage your credential > Windows Credentials > Add a generic credential >

> Internet address will be git:https://github.com and you need to type
> in your username and password will be your GitHub Personal Access
> Token => Click Ok and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using proxy settings in your android studio. Follow these STEPS and set proxy to automatic, then try again.

```
Settings ==> Appearance & Behaviour => System Settings > HTTP Proxy ==> Auto-detect , then save and try to login again.
```

Answer (score -1):

I deleted all tokens and generated new one with all access,
Now it's working...

Answer (score -1):

Generating the Token as explained worked for my perfect.
Need to grant the correct permissions to such token.

Answer (score -1):

1. server => `github.com` to change `http://github.com`
2. use access token no password