# uploading android project on github - aggregate exception

Tags: android, git, github

I wanted to upload an android project on github and thus followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github) stackoverflow's answer. But instead of success message in last, I get a message saying commit has failed and aggregate exception has occured. I searched the net but found no such case. Repository has been created and most of the project is uploaded. I want to upload rest of project but don't know how. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you go **Settings->Version Control - > GitHub** and click **Test** works or stop allready there ?

Comment: It gives me **connection successful**

Comment: May you post screenshot where it stops ?

Comment: I have not taken the screenshot first time. I think I can't redo the same process as repository is already created. My message appears at the same place where the successful message appears in the screenshot which is posted in the answer I refferred to.