# Android Studio connecting to Git hub

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm trying to connect Android Studio to Git Hub.

I've followed this tutorial [How to add an Android Studio project to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github) (top comment).

I've tested my connection to git and the path to the git.exe and both are succesfful. I get an error on my initial commit saying that git doesn't know who I am and to run `"git config --global user.name "username"` (I put in my username) ". I did that and tried running again and it still doesn't work.

Also, what should be entered into the remote name?

Thanks

Comment: In your console try `git config --global --list` and see if the user.name is set

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your username in " "

Check this out, this will help you: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Comment: I did put my username there. Using that git application, where do I point android studio to?

Comment: You don't have to point it anywhere. Just setup git (username and email id) and start pushing your changes to github.

Comment: I figured out how to get it work but the I have a new issue. I exited android studio and reopened the same project. However I don't see how to commit and push the new changes. I had to re-enable version control. Once I did that, I hit the green up arrow (commit/push) but it says there's not changes. It's like since I closed and re-opened it isn't connected to that repository anymore.