# How to link github and android studio?

Tags: android-studio, github

I'm getting issues and finding it difficult to link my android studio code in the git repository. Can someone please explain how to link it.

Comment: please share what you have tried and where you have stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an Android Studio project to GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github)