# Android Studio check out from Github do anything

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to clone project from Github by: **Check out project from version control** --> **Git** --> **Here I'm filling textboxes with stuff i want download** --> **Clicking Clone**  and my window is disapearing and happens nothing. Not even one comunication, just window is closing after i clicked clone

Comment: [This] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github) might help

Comment: Glad it did! Cheers ;)