# android studio no current branch

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I want to upload my android studio project to GitHub but this error appears

Can't finish GitHub sharing process: Successfully created project 'test' on GitHub, but initial push failed: no current branch

what to do?

Comment: Did you init your local repository? git init

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github

Comment: i did all these steps but this error appears :(